# rvmsudo -s fails with syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm having a problem I thought was due to Passenger, but it's because `rvmsudo` is experiencing a syntax error:

/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `rvmsudo` is not picking up the environment correctly because of a syntax error. `rvmsudo` silently fails, but `rvmsudo -s` shows the error:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The culprit is this:

```
rvm_version=1.25.27 (master)
```

Having that `(master)` on the end screws everything up.